# how can I create a new hardware device sensor in Android?

Tags: android, kernel, hardware, sensors, android-kernel

I am an electronic engineer and I have also experience developing Android apps (Activity, services, broadcast...).

Currently, I am trying to read the data of an ambient ligth sensor BH1750 connected by i2c in a JAVA app, using a snapdragon 845 development board as this [one](https://www.intrinsyc.com/snapdragon-embedded-development-kits/open-q-845-usom-development-kit/). The snapdragon runs Android 9 Pie based on kernel v4.9.

I know how to use the sensor framework to read values from the sensors in an JAVA app, using the `SensorManager` class, `listener` and the corresponding callbacks such as `onSensorChange`. However, I don't know how to set up or configure the BH1750 sensor to be recognised by the Android system and define it as `TYPE_LIGTH` to be able to use the sensor framework in a JAVA app.

I have found the driver of the BH1750 sensor for Android systems, it is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common.git/+/ASB-2018-01-05_4.9-o-release/drivers/iio/light/bh1750.c).

How can I add the sensor driver to Android? Where should I place the driver within the file system?

Once the driver is set to the kernel, how can I configure the Hardware Abstraction layer (HAL) to recognise the sensor from the JAVA app?

Thank you in advance!